# Getting the radio button selected one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add styles to the `radion button` with my css below,

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">

.sizes input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
    margin:10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sizes input[type=radio] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: tahoma, arial;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.sizes input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: #be5559;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sizes .checked {
  color: #be5559;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>  

<!--[if IE 8]>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".sizes label").click(function() {
    $(".sizes label").removeClass("checked");
    $(this).addClass("checked");
   });
  });
 </script>
 <![endif]-->

</head>
```

But the problem is if click on `First one` the second button is also getting selected in Mozilla , while it works in IE 8  . I have created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/San_Krish/RS4HA/2/)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Invalid matching attributes `id` and `for`. See http://jsfiddle.net/RS4HA/3/

Comment: updated my fiddle , please check it now

Comment: It is working perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/RS4HA/3/

Comment: In IE 8 it selects only one radio button at a time , i mean either for span 1: or span 2: which ever is clicked

Comment: Move away from IE < 9.

Comment: its the fate . we are still supporting our app for IE8 :( . Any suggestions ?

Comment: Lol JSFiddle itself isn't working in IE8.

Comment: yep ;( that is the biggest flaw in ie8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning wrong `for` attribute to label. Label should have same `for` attribute value as the `id` of element it is targeting.

E.g.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radio" value="true">
<label for="radio4">Un-Subscribe</label>
```

Here is modified jsFiddle : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RS4HA/5/)

Comment: In IE 8 it selects only one radio button at a time , i mean either for span 1: or span 2: which ever is clicked

Comment: Check this fiddle in IE8... http://jsfiddle.net/RS4HA/9/. Is it giving same result?

Comment: @sankrish researched on net & got this answer : " While IE8 understands adjacent sibling selectors, it doesn't understand the checked pseudo-element, so, unfortunately, you can't make your code IE8-friendly by using CSS only."

Comment: thanks @rohan . Is there anyway i could achieve it using `jquery` , as you could see this `<!--[if IE 8]>` in my code